# What is the syntax for checking if two strings are the same in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

What is the syntax for checking if strings are identical?

in Java it is: 
    string1.equals(string2);

but what is it in objective C?

Comment: I assume you don't actually want to check if they are identical or are the same string but actually want to check if they have the same contents.

Comment: Yeah, just if they have the same contents, in my code I know that they are different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `isEqualToString` for the most accurate results. I've included a couple examples on how to use it.

```
NSString *aString = foo;
NSString *bString = bar;
if ([aString isEqualToString:bString]) {
    NSLog("Match");
}
else NSLog("No Match");
//No match.

NSString *aString = foo;
NSString *bString = bar;
if ([aString isEqualToString:@"foo"]) {
    NSLog("Double Foo!");
}
else NSLog("No Match");
//Double Foo!

NSString *aString = foo;
NSString *bString = bar;
if (![aString isEqualToString:bString]) {
    NSLog("No Match");
}
else NSLog("Match");
//No Match
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *String1, *String2;
if([String1 compare: String2] == NSOrderedSame)
    //They are the same
```

`NSOrderedSame` is defined as zero, so you can write

```
if(![String1 compare: String2])
    //Equals
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `isEqualToString:` and `compare:` ?

Comment: It's shorter. Also, it's a natural fit for longtime users of `strcmp`.

Comment: `-compare:` will give you a bad result if either `self` or the argument is `nil`. So you should check for `nil` beforehand and do special processing if your use case includes potential `nil` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Use the specific string equality message

```
[string1 isEqualToString: string2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [isEqualToString.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_)

```
 if ( [stringOne isEqualToString: stringTwo] ) { }
```